Why is it traditionally thought that book of daniel's author is Daniel?
I understand that most scholars think that book of daniel is a forgery and definitely not written in the 6th century BC and not written by Daniel.
What strikes me is why christians traditionally think that the book was written by Daniel ? In the book itself, first 1-6 chapters, it's written in 3rd person and not 1st which definitely don't mean at all that book was written by Daniel.  For sure, 7-12 sometimes talk about in 1st person but what solid argument does this give that book was written by Daniel ?
Would you be able to shed lights about why christians think that it was written by Daniel ? what's their reasoning ?

A question like Would you be able to shed lights about why christians think that it was written by Daniel? is probably more on topic on http://christianity.stackexchange.com. a question like 'what is the evidence for Daniel being the author of the book of Daniel' is better for hermeneutics

Welcome Giorgi.  there is already a question that deals with this. It asks more generally but includes and answer to your question. In the meantime here is a thoughtful article from a Christian perspective.

It is quite common for an author to write of themselves in the third person for part or all of their autobiography. The first part of Daniel is a history written in the third person. The majority of the book is in the first person and expresses, intimately, the visions he saw.
